# Drawing contures on canvas with OpenCV

Tags: python, image, opencv, graphics, screenshot

I want to detect contours in freshly made screenshot, and while I can access number of contours found, I cannot draw them on black canva, this is my code:

```
while True:
    keyboard.wait('right')


    img = pyautogui.screenshot()
    img = cv.cvtColor(np.array(img), cv.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    img = CropImage(img)

    blank = np.zeros(img.shape[:2], dtype='uint8')

    gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret, thresh = cv.threshold(gray, 122, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)

    contours, hierarchies = cv.findContours(thresh, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    print(f'{len(contours) } contours found')

    cv.drawContours(blank, contours, -1, (0,255,0))

    cv.imwrite('C:/screeny/screen0.png', blank)
```

Comment: What error message do you get and at what point in your code?

Comment: Drawing in color (0,255,0) to a single-channel images will draw black contours (on black background in your case). Try color (255,0,0) instead aor make blank be a 3-channel image.

Comment: @micka thank you, it solved my issue